# How can I include both "Message" and "MessageTemplate" in the Serilog JsonFormatter output?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I'm using Serlog 2.10,
Writing to Console (as human-readable text),
and to RollingFile - with JsonFormatter.

I want in the output JSON to have both: "Message" and "MessageTemplate" nodes,

However I'm getting only either "Message" or "MessageTemplate", but not both.

Here's how it's being configured:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.RollingFile(new JsonFormatter(), "logs/log-{Date}.log")
                .CreateLogger();
```

I followed the instructions on this page:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact

I've tried all 3 Json Formatters:

- "RenderedCompactJsonFormatter" - puts "@m" (Message) in the output
- "CompactJsonFormatter" - puts "@mt" (MessageTemlate) in the output
- "JsonFormatter" - puts "MessageTemplate" in the output

How can I include both of them in the output?

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Serilog.Expressions*](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) can do this:

```cs
  .WriteTo.RollingFile(
    new ExpressionTemplate(
      "{ {Timestamp: @t, Level: @l, MessageTemplate: @mt, Message: @m, Exception: @x, " +
      "Properties: if IsDefined(@p[?]) then @p else undefined()} }" + Environment.NewLine,
      "logs/log-{Date}.log")
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an optional parameter `renderMessage` to the [JsonFormatter constructor](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/63bff1e93f8141b1ffa9f1632d05f90c72c42f65/src/Serilog/Formatting/Json/JsonFormatter.cs#L40C7-L40C7) that adds `RenderedMessage` to the json:

[image: JsonFormatter]

Comment: Please never post screenshots of code. Always post code as text and use the formatting tool to format it as code. Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question as text and get properly formatted and [no Screenshots of Code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write your own formatter. Start from e.g. the [JsonFormatter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Formatting/Json/JsonFormatter.cs) and only use those parts that are valid for your requirements.